# How Can a VPC ping the Router through an Etherswitch that behaves in one port as router and in the other as switch

Tags: cisco, routing, vlan, ipv4, switchport

In the following topology my main purpose is to:

1)PC11 ping Router(R)

2)PC11 ping PC13

ESW10:

In gig0/3 has the **no switchport** command and a given IP address.

In gig0/2 it has the **switchport access VLAN 10** command.

In gig0/0 it has a given IP and the **no switchport** command.

In gi0/1 has **switchport access VLAN 10** command.

PC11 can ping PC9

R can ping ESW10

ESW10 can ping ESW11.

[image]

So my question is what do I need to add and where for PC11 and PC9 to ping R and eventually PC13

Device Configs:

ROUTER

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0 
ip address 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0 
duplex full 
interface GigabitEtherneto/1
ip address 192.168.3.1 255.255.255.0 
duplex auto
```

ESW10

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0 
no switchport 
ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0 
negotiation auto
interface GigabitEthernet0/1 
switchport access vlan 10 
switchport mode access 
negotiation auto
interface GigabitEthernet0/2 
switchport access vlan 10 
switchport mode access 
negotiation auto
interface GigabitEthernet0/3 
no switchport 
ip address 192.168.2.2 255.255.255.0 
negotiation auto
```

ESW11

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0 
no switchport 
ip address 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.0 
negotiation auto
interface GigabitEthernet0/1 
switchport access vlan 10 
switchport mode access 
negotiation auto
interface GigabitEtherneto/2 
switchport access vlan 10 
switchport mode access 
negotiation auto
```

Comment: Please add the full configurations to your question (using the `{ }` editor function). We cannot guess what you did wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not include the full configurations as asked, but there seem to be a few problems:

- I do not see that you have enable routing on EWS10 with the `ip routing` command.
- I do not see that you have added a route to `10.168.3.0/24` on ESW
- I do not see that you have added a route to `192.168.1.0/24` on R1.

Routers need to know how to reach networks other than their directly attached networks, either with static routes or with a routing protocol.

Comment: I put only this config because it was what needed for the answer and the only config the devices had. What you said helped a lot and one last thing that doesnt work is that PC11 cant ping ESW10. What do i need to do about that?

Comment: If you had put in the entire configuration, then we could see right away wat the problem is. What you thought was relevant was only part of what was actually relevant. Please, when someone asks you for the full configuration, please provide it. If you really knew everything that is relevant, you would not be asking fo help.

Comment: @ECHO, the switch address should be on an SVI for that VLAN Normally, you connect switch-to-switch with a trunk interface, and each switch gets an address on an SVI, which is a virtual interface that never goes down in the case of an interface cable being removed. The design you have is something that would not be used. You would also configure an IP default gateway on a layer-2 switch (never on a device with routing enabled) like ESW 11..